# Improving the performance of a program in C

Tags: c, performance

I'm writing a program for an assignment, and my program is currently only about 30ms too slow. However, I'm not entirely sure how to speed up my program. I tried to precompute some of the functions inside my loops, but I'm not really sure it helped...

The purpose of the program is to receive a bunch of inputs and determine whether a specific number is the majority in the input, and as a follow-up determine any runners up.

An example input might be: `1 2 2 2 1 0`

The program would output:

```
majority: 2
runner-up: 1
```

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int majorityCheck (int length, int arrMajority[]);
int runnerCheck (int length, int arrRunner[]);

unsigned int var, x, y;

int majorityCheck(int length, int arr[]){ //checks for maj
    int var, x, y;
    for(x=0;x<length-1;x++){
        var=0;
        for(y=0;y<length-1;y++){
            if(arr[y]==arr[x]){
                var++;
            }
        }
        if(2*var>length-1){
            return arr[x];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int runnerCheck(int length, int arr[]){ //checks for runnerup
    for(x=0;x<length-1;x++){
        var=0;
        for(y=0;y<length-1;y++){
            if(arr[y]==arr[x]){
                var++; //var is just a random incrementing tool
            }
        }
        if(2*var<length-1 && 4*var>length-1){
            return arr[x];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int input;
    int *list=malloc(sizeof(int));
    int size=1;
    int numRunner;

    while(scanf("%u", &input)){
        if(input==0){
            break;}
            list[size-1]=input;
            size++;
            list=(int*)realloc(list, size*sizeof(int));
        }

    int numMajority=majorityCheck(size, list);
    if(numMajority==(-1)){
        printf("majority: NONE");}
        else{
            numRunner=runnerCheck(size, list);

            if(numRunner==(-1)){
                printf("majority: %d\nrunner-up: NONE", numMajority);
                }else{
                    printf("majority: %d\nrunner-up: %d", numMajority, numRunner);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the occurrences and output the hightest two?

Comment: Your `y` loops could start from `x+1` as everything before x has been procesed already.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes, that's correct.

Comment: "30ms too slow" - as compared to what? Speed can be achieved by using a faster processor. IMHO, it's the time complexity that matters.

Comment: Generally if you want to have performance improvement, you need to look at improving the algorithm. e.g. In this case, you are calculating the majority and runner up in two separate loops. You can look into calculating them in a single loop. i.e. O(n)

Comment: can we have negative value as input?

Comment: Do not `realloc` for every value. `malloc` a larger chunk of memory (100 values for example) and realloc twice as much memory if needed.

Comment: The 30 ms too slow with only six input values? 30ms is a lot for most modern controllers. Have you set compiler optimization to speed?

Comment: @suvojit_007 No, all inputs are positive.

Comment: @A.R.C. I'm submitting the code to a university website so I don't know how it's compiling.

Comment: @4Head I guess this problem can be optimized further if you know the range of number as all the number is going to be positive

Comment: @suvojit_007 How can I do this. Just change every int to an unsigned int?

Comment: If you know the range of the numbers, for example 1-1000 you only need one array to hold 1000 elements. So your algorithm must change entirely.

Comment: If you know the range then you could store the occurrence in an auxiliary array in a single scan.

Comment: @4386427 A majority, at least in this case, corresponds to more than half (of the input).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [several other Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+majority) except for the runner-up aspect. There is a [web page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/) that gives several algorithms. Its Method 3, using Moore’s Voting Algorithm, is O(*n*) to find the majority element. Then a runner-up can also be found in O(*n*) by removing the majority elements and repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do:

1. Sort the array using merge sort.
2. Go through the array comparing two elements at a time. So first compare 0 with 1, then 1 with 2... Check if element n equals n-1. In doing so, determine how many times each number shows up.  If you see a new number, set its count to 1 and if matches the number after it then increment its count. Otherwise, create a new count for the next number.

So, as an example, consider array `0, 1, 1`.  First you will look at value `0` (at index 0) and store it's count somewhere. Then you will compare it to `1` (at index 1) and see if they match. If they do, then increment the count for `0`, otherwise, store the count of `1` as 1 in another variable. Since they don't match, you'll create a variable where you'll store the count of `1`.  Now repeat this process when comparing `1` at index 1 and 2... You'll end up with variables that hold counts for `0` and `1`. You can just go through them to find the rankings of most occurrences.

You can use an array of structs that holds the number and its count if you want algorithm to be able to handle more than just the two highest counts.

On the other hand, if you know you will only need two numbers then you can just keep track of the numbers that have the two highest counts in four variables (`firstNum`, `firstCount`, `secondNum`,  `secondCount`).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I basically solved this by precomputing the functions inside the loops and using `#include <math.h>`

For some reason that shaved almost a second off the execution of my program.

Comment: Would you care to share what exactly you did to improve the performance? How did you precompute the functions insdie the loops? How does `<math.h>`, help you with that?

Comment: This “answer” makes no sense. The functions depend on data read at execution time and therefore cannot be precomputed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must realize that your two functions `majorityCheck` and `runnerCheck` are practically identical. They only differ by one line: the single if statement. In short, they do exactly the same work but return an expected value on different conditions.

Since you only have two expected values (majority and runner-up), you can surely imagine combining your functions into one that returns both of these values. How you return two values is your choice; you can return a structure representing a pair of `int`, or you can add "out" parameters to the function. The only part left is storing these values instead of directly returning from the function. Here is an example.

```
int majorityRunnerUpCheck(int array[], int length, int* majority, int* runnerUp) {
    int count, i, j;
    *majority = -1;
    *runnerUp = -1;

    // Note: if you use '<' (less than), then you want "length", not "length-1"
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        // Note: here as well
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        // Note: and here, too;
        // otherwise you could have a majority with 3 out of 6
        // (unless you do want that)
        // Also, length/2 conveys the meaning better than var*2 (or count*2)
        if (count > length/2) {
            // Store the majority
            *majority = array[i];
        }
        // Note: are you sure you need the runner-up occurences to be more than a
        // fourth of the input? I don't think that's the definition of a runner-up...
        else if (count < length/2 && count > length/4) {
            // Store the runner-up
            *runnerUp = array[i];
        }
    }

    // Make the return value useful: let it be the number of expected values
    // you got, that is 2 for both, 1 for a majority but no runner-up, and 0
    // for no majority.
    if (*majority != -1) {
        if (*runnerUp != -1) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this can be further improved. But it would require redesigning the algorithm. Here is what I would have done, inspired by counting-sort. I assume the values in your array are between 0 and 100. If that's not the case, you can still use some other inspiration, like radix-sort, or hash-sort (counting-sort but using a hash table instead of an array), or even bucket-sort...

```
int majorityRunnerUpCheck(int array[], int length, int* majority, int* runnerUp) {
    int counts[101] = {0};
    int i, r = 0;
    *majority = -1;
    *runnerUp = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        counts[array[i]]++;
        if (counts[array[i]] > length/2) {
            *majority = array[i];
            r+=2;
        } else if (counts[i] < length/2 && counts[i] > length/4) {
            *runnerUp = array[i];
            r++;
        }
    }

    return r != 0 ? r-1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the answers if we have the range of the number and all the input numbers are positive, then we can solve this problem in `linear` time.

We will count the occurrence of each number in an auxiliary array and then we will scan the auxiliary array to get the `majority` and `runner-up` element.

In this example, I'm assuming the range of the input number is `0-1000`.

> Drawbacks of this technique:
>
> This could run in linear time but in terms of space complexity,
>   this technique is not that efficient if the range is too high.  We
>   need to know the range of input in advance to allocate the memory
>   for the auxiliary array.  If all the elements are unique then this
>   algorithm will give you any    two random number unless you handle all
>   the cases properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number,i;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    int num[number];

    for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);

    //create an array of 1000 elements
    int size = 1000;
    int auxiliary[size];

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        auxiliary[i]=0; //initialize count with 0
    for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        auxiliary[num[i]]++;  //count the occurrence 

    int majority,runner_up;  

     majority = 0;
     runner_up = 0;  

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
       {
            if(auxiliary[i]>auxiliary[majority])
            {
                majority = i;
            }

       }

   for(i=1;i<size;i++)
       {

            if(auxiliary[i]>auxiliary[runner_up] && i!=majority)
            {
                runner_up = i;
            }

       }   

       if(runner_up==0)
            {
                printf("MAJORITY>> %d",majority);
                return 0;
            }


      printf("MAJORITY >> %d , RUNNER UP>>%d",majority,runner_up);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To speed this up properly, first realise that you don't need to store the numbers but could store how many times each number has occurred instead, and that this can be done with very little expense (none of the overhead of `malloc()`, `realloc()` or building and iterating through linked lists). For a crude and untested example:

```
#define MAX_VALUE 1234

int occurrences[MAX_VALUE+1];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int input;
    unsigned int total = 0;
    unsigned int currentMostFrequent = 0;
    unsigned int currentSecondMostFrequent = 0;

    while(scanf("%u", &input)){
        if(input==0){
            break;
        } else if(input > MAX_VALUE) {
            break;
        } else {
            total++;
            occurrences[input]++;
            if(occurrences[input] > currentSecondMostFrequent) {
                if(occurrences[input] > currentMostFrequent) {
                    currentSecondMostFrequent = currentMostFrequent;
                    currentMostFrequent = input;
                } else {
                    currentSecondMostFrequent = input;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(occurrences[currentMostFrequent] > total/2) {
        printf("majority: %d\n", currentMostFrequent);
        if(currentSecondMostFrequent > 0) {
            printf("runner up: %d\n", currentSecondMostFrequent);
        } else {
            printf("runner up: NONE\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("majority: NONE\n");
        if(currentMostFrequent > 0) {
            printf("runner up: %d\n", currentMostFrequent);
        } else {
            printf("runner up: NONE\n");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What reason is there to believe the `MAX_VALUE` required for the problem is small enough that `int occurrences[MAX_VALUE+1];` is reasonable?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Assuming modern operating systems on modern computers; using `UINT_MAX` would probably be fine, given that modern computers are 64-bit (huge virtual address space), modern operating systems use "allocate on write" semantics (a large array full of zeros costs almost no RAM initially) and that this is a school assignment (unlikely to be more than 10 values, so unlikely that more than 10 pages/40 KiB of RAM will be used for the entire 16 GiB array)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Also note that the opposite can happen - e.g. the user enters billions of numbers (e.g. by redirecting a file to stdin) where all numbers are from 1 to 200; where a linked list (probably costing 16 bytes per number) can cost more RAM than an `int myArray[UINT_MAX]` and significantly more RAM than a `int myArray[201]`.